# Put int to existing buffer

Tags: c++, int, buffer

I have a code below, but i can't put `int` to my `buffer`.

```
unsigned char  buffer[1024];
buffer[0] = 0x44;
u_long fd = htonl(VERSION);
memcpy(buffer+1, &fd, 4);
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Changing question is bad habbit...ask another question if so necessary.It will render others answer useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  `ntohl(buffer[1]);` value of  `buffer[1]` will be taken (a char) and will be casted into `long`.This will cause on a little endian machine to take value at `&buffer[1]` which is obviously 0 for value less than 2<sup>24</sup>(unsigned) as you have called `ntohl` earlier which reverses byte order.

And if you are really interested to look into the buffer then try

```
int *f =(int*) (&buffer[1]);
printf("\n %u \n", ntohl(*f));//Also *f but then you have to paste it in calculator to see allignment
```

Comment: Thanks! All ok, but i have a problem. When try to read this `int` in my C# server application, i have an error 'Number overflow'. Do you know something about it?

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the value into the buffer correctly, but you are not checking it correctly afterwards.  `ntohl(buffer[1])` is retrieving the 1-byte `unsigned char` value that is inside the second slot of the buffer by itself, and then extending it to a 4-byte value when passing it to `ntohl()`.  What you need to do instead is retrieve the 4-byte `unsigned long` value that occupies the second, third, fourth, and fifth slots of the buffer and use it as-is:

```
ntohl(*reinterpret_cast<u_long*>(buffer+1));
```

Or:

```
u_long version;
memcpy(&version, buffer+1, 4);
ntohl(version);
```